# Conflict between WOW.js and One Page Scroll

Tags: javascript, plugins, viewport, animate.css

I'm trying to combine the following JS plugins on a site that I'm working on,

https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll
One Page Scroll, by Pete R.

http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/
WOW.js, by Matthieu Aussaguel (together with animate.css)

On each section I want to animate in its content as the transition completes, but the WOW.js / CSS animations doesn't seem to take effect and I'm stuck with invisible elements. It seems the on reveal animations is somehow in conflict with the viewport / pages setup from One Page Scroll. Any ideas? Something I'm missing? I set the treshhold of WOW.js to 0. No JS errors showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The short answer is that you can't easily do this.

See [issue 61](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/61) for more information. Basically, the On Page Scroll plugin does its custom callbacks on page scroll that prevents WOW.js from triggering its own scroll handlers. On Page Scroll would have to be changed in order for this to work.

Comment: Oh okay. I suspected this would be the case.

Comment: Sadness but now I at least understand what's happening.